# How can I get back into the Pump Room?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

So I'm wrapping up the last of the Riddler challenges, and I only have one left.  It's the one in the Pump Room in the Caves section of the map.

Trying to get there from the BatCave/Sewers, its blocked off by one of those electric fences.  On the map, it looks like there's an entrance from Arkham West, but I don't see a corresponding entrance when I'm in that area of the map.

How can I get back into that area?  Did I miss one of the control boxes somewhere?  Is there really an entrance from Arkham West?

As to where I'm at in the progress of the game, my current objective is to go to the party.

Thanks again!

Comment: You can get there at this point, 100%.  I don't remember having a problem but if nobody's answered this by the time I get home I'll swing by there and have a look.

Comment: Awesome.  The one that's left is in the left wing of the pump rooms, if that makes any difference.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer so I'll just leave a comment, but have you checked out any guides or walkthroughs?

Comment: Not yet; trying to avoid that since I have a tendency to keep reading further than I need to, and don't want to spoil anything

Comment: Looks like I'll be playing some Batman when I get home at this rate.  @Jim B, I assume you have the map for this; which specific challenge are you missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  I missed a control box in the previous room (which disabled the electric fence) and the entrance from Arkham west is in the northeast section, high up on a ledge.

Comment: I got super busy and didn't have a chance to look yet; glad you figured it out though!